# How do I get my question reopened as I would really like a resolution?

Tags: support, close-reasons

I asked a question which was closed as a "Duplicate Question":

- [How do I add customized wallpapers so they appear in the dynamic unity greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123381/how-do-i-add-customized-wallpapers-in-usr-share-backrounds-in-12-04)

I even acknowledged this by linking the potential duplications to my question.

How do I reopen the question as it was specific to 12.04 and The duplications cited did not give me a resolution.  I probably would have expected a comment from an experienced user asking something like, if my resolution is not in the links can I explain better what differentiates it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it reopened by either leaving a comment on the question, flagging the question for moderator attention, or by posting here on meta, as you already have! There appears to be some conflict as to whether it *actually* is a duplicate. I'll let the community debate if it is, in the mean time it's been reopened. Though if found to be a duplicate by the community it'll likely be re-closed.